# Android Studio - table *** has no column named ***

Tags: android, sqlite

I have seen his issue posted all over in my searching, but none of the answers have solved this for me. I am trying to write to my reservations table, but am getting : "table reservations has no column named KEY_REST_STATE". I have tried uninstalling the app, restarting the phone and made sure to increase the database number every time. I have been staring at this code for hours and can't find the issue. Please help!!

**DatabaseHelper.java**

```
package com.example.findaraunt;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;


public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 10;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "theReserve";
    private static final String TABLE_RES = "reservations";
    private static final String KEY_RESID = "resid";
    private static final String KEY_USERID = "userid";
    private static final String KEY_REST_NAME = "rest_name";
    private static final String KEY_REST_ADDRESS = "rest_address";
    private static final String KEY_REST_CITY = "rest_city";
    private static final String KEY_REST_STATE = "rest_state";
    private static final String KEY_REST_ZIP = "rest_zip";
    private static final String KEY_RES_DATE = "res_date";
    private static final String KEY_RES_TIME = "res_time";
    private static final String KEY_RES_SIZE = "res_size";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        String CREATE_RES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_RES + "(" + KEY_RESID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_USERID + " INT,"+ KEY_REST_NAME +
                " TEXT," + KEY_REST_ADDRESS + " TEXT," + KEY_REST_CITY + " TEXT," + KEY_REST_STATE + " TEXT," + KEY_REST_ZIP +
                " INT," + KEY_RES_DATE + " TEXT," + KEY_RES_TIME + " TEXT," + KEY_RES_SIZE + " INT" + ")";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_RES_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1){
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading settings database from version " + i + " to "
                + i1);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_RES);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void dropTable(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_RES);
    }

    void addReservation(Reservations reserv){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put("KEY_USERID", reserv.getUserid());
        values.put("KEY_REST_NAME", reserv.getRest_name());
        values.put("KEY_REST_ADDRESS", reserv.getRest_address());
        values.put("KEY_REST_CITY", reserv.getRest_city());
        values.put("KEY_REST_STATE", reserv.getRest_state());
        values.put("KEY_REST_ZIP", reserv.getRest_zip());
        values.put("KEY_RES_DATE", reserv.getRes_date());
        values.put("KEY_RES_TIME", reserv.getRes_time());
        values.put("KEY_RES_SIZE", reserv.getRes_size());

        db.insert(TABLE_RES, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    Reservations getReservation(int userid, int resid){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_RES, new String[]{KEY_RESID, KEY_USERID, KEY_REST_NAME,KEY_REST_ADDRESS,KEY_REST_CITY,KEY_REST_STATE,KEY_REST_ZIP,
                KEY_RES_DATE,KEY_RES_TIME,KEY_RES_SIZE}, KEY_RESID + "=? AND " + KEY_USERID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(resid)}, null, null, null, null);
        if(cursor != null){
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }

        Reservations res = new Reservations(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)),
                cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5),
                Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(6)), cursor.getString(7), cursor.getString(8),
                Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(9)));

        return res;
    }

    public List<Reservations> getAllReservations(){
        List<Reservations> reservationsList = new ArrayList<>();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_RES;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            Reservations reservations = new Reservations();
            reservations.setResid(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            reservations.setUserid(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)));
            reservations.setRest_name(cursor.getString(2));
            reservations.setRest_address(cursor.getString(3));
            reservations.setRest_city(cursor.getString(4));
            reservations.setRest_state(cursor.getString(5));
            reservations.setRest_zip(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(6)));
            reservations.setRes_date(cursor.getString(7));
            reservations.setRes_time(cursor.getString(8));
            reservations.setRes_size(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(9)));

            reservationsList.add(reservations);
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return reservationsList;
    }
 }
```

**ViewEditReservations.java**

```
package com.example.findaraunt;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;

import java.util.List;

public class ViewEditReservations2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;
    String text = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_edit_reservations2);

        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        Menu menu = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(3);
        menuItem.setChecked(true);

        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.navigation_home:
                        Intent i1 = new Intent (ViewEditReservations2.this,ViewEditReservations.class);
                        startActivity(i1);
                        break;
                    case R.id.navigation_search:
                        break;
                    case R.id.navigation_profile:
                        Intent i3 = new Intent (ViewEditReservations2.this,ReviewRestaurant.class);
                        startActivity(i3);
                        break;
                    case R.id.navigation_logout:
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

        DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        //inserting reservations
        db.addReservation(new Reservations(1, "Applebees","123 Sesame St","Big Bird",
                "AZ",12345,"7/1/2019","7:00pm",4));
        db.addReservation(new Reservations(1,"Olive Garden","1 W Olive St","Tapenade","CA",
                    54321,"7/4/2019","12:00pm",6));
        db.addReservation(new Reservations(2,"Marlows Tevern","88 Marlow Ave","Tavern","NY",
                    32143, "8/15/2019","10:00am",2));

        //reading and displaying all reservations
        List<Reservations> reservations = db.getAllReservations();

        for (Reservations r : reservations){
            String log = "userid: " + r.getUserid() +
                    ", REST_NAME" + r.getRest_name() +
                    ", REST_ADDRESS" + r.getRest_address() +
                    ", REST_CITY" + r.getRest_city() +
                    ", REST_STATE" + r.getRest_state() +
                    ", REST_ZIP" + r.getRest_zip() +
                    ", RES_DATE" + r.getRes_date() +
                    ", RES_TIME" + r.getRes_time() +
                    ", RES_SIZE" + r.getRes_size() + "\n";
            text = text + log;
        }
        textView.setText(text);
    }
}
```

**Logcat**

```
2019-07-02 03:37:34.710 12111-12111/? W/mple.findaraun: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2019-07-02 03:37:35.524 12111-12111/com.example.findaraunt W/mple.findaraun: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
2019-07-02 03:37:35.525 12111-12111/com.example.findaraunt W/mple.findaraun: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
2019-07-02 03:37:35.986 12111-12161/com.example.findaraunt W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2019-07-02 03:37:36.048 12111-12111/com.example.findaraunt E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
2019-07-02 03:37:40.730 12111-12111/com.example.findaraunt W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@7e4db54
2019-07-02 03:37:40.816 12111-12111/com.example.findaraunt W/ContentValues: Upgrading settings database from version 9 to 10
2019-07-02 03:37:40.826 12111-12111/com.example.findaraunt E/SQLiteLog: (1) table reservations has no column named KEY_REST_STATE
2019-07-02 03:37:40.832 12111-12111/com.example.findaraunt E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting KEY_REST_STATE=AZ KEY_RES_TIME=7:00pm KEY_REST_ADDRESS=123 Sesame St KEY_RES_DATE=7/1/2019 KEY_REST_NAME=Applebees KEY_USERID=1 KEY_REST_CITY=Big Bird KEY_REST_ZIP=12345 KEY_RES_SIZE=4
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table reservations has no column named KEY_REST_STATE (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO reservations(KEY_REST_STATE,KEY_RES_TIME,KEY_REST_ADDRESS,KEY_RES_DATE,KEY_REST_NAME,KEY_USERID,KEY_REST_CITY,KEY_REST_ZIP,KEY_RES_SIZE) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:903)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:514)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1562)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1433)
        at com.example.findaraunt.DatabaseHelper.addReservation(DatabaseHelper.java:72)
        at com.example.findaraunt.ViewEditReservations2.onCreate(ViewEditReservations2.java:57)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
2019-07-02 03:37:40.843 12111-12111/com.example.findaraunt E/SQLiteLog: (1) table reservations has no column named KEY_REST_STATE
2019-07-02 03:37:40.846 12111-12111/com.example.findaraunt E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting KEY_REST_STATE=CA KEY_RES_TIME=12:00pm KEY_REST_ADDRESS=1 W Olive St KEY_RES_DATE=7/4/2019 KEY_REST_NAME=Olive Garden KEY_USERID=1 KEY_REST_CITY=Tapenade KEY_REST_ZIP=54321 KEY_RES_SIZE=6
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table reservations has no column named KEY_REST_STATE (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO reservations(KEY_REST_STATE,KEY_RES_TIME,KEY_REST_ADDRESS,KEY_RES_DATE,KEY_REST_NAME,KEY_USERID,KEY_REST_CITY,KEY_REST_ZIP,KEY_RES_SIZE) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:903)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:514)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1562)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1433)
        at com.example.findaraunt.DatabaseHelper.addReservation(DatabaseHelper.java:72)
        at com.example.findaraunt.ViewEditReservations2.onCreate(ViewEditReservations2.java:59)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are hard coding the value **KEY_REST_STATE** as a string for the column name. What you want is to use the **String variable named KEY_REST_STATE** that holds the value **rest_state** which is the column name. You need to apply this throughout your **addReservation** method.

Change :-

```
values.put("KEY_REST_STATE", reserv.getRest_state());
```

to :-

```
values.put(KEY_REST_STATE, reserv.getRest_state());
```

- There will be no need to uninstall the App, as the change isn't a change to the Schema.

Comment: I knew it was something obvious. Thanks a bunch!!